# How to restore header and footer after appendix

Tags: header-footer, appendix, pagestyle

I'm currently working on my bachelor thesis. My university wants the ending to be like this:

- Bibliography
- Appendices
- List of Figures
- List of Tables

I'm using the appendix environment for this setup.
But the two pages after my appendix there are no header or footer.

Does anybody know why they simply disappear?
It seems like there is something like `\pagestyle{plain}`

I hope you can help me.
Thanks

Comment: It helps to provide a Minimal Working Example we can copy and run which reproduces the problem  (and contains as little unrelated stuff as possible).  OTOH, you might consider the appendix package and use \begin{appendix} and \end{appendix}.

Comment: I'm already using the appendix environment.
I thought about that, but I didn't know how to set up a proper minimal example, because I found some other problems (pageref to the bibliography in the toc refers to the last page of the bib).
That's why I'm not even sure, if that's only a problem with the appendix.